# why can't I use macOS's builtin screen sharing to connect to a Windows machine running realvnc server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Can somebody please explain why I cannot use macOS's builtin screen sharing app to connect to Windows machines running the RealVNC server? 
I can only connect to them using the RealVNC viewer.

Comment: How are you trying to connect?  Use "Connect to Server"  in Finder and type the server URI as "vnc://server.ip.address"

Comment: Yes, I use the Finder method. I also tried various other VNC clients, such as Screens and Chicken.